# Differences between zu Haus/nach Haus

Tags: preposition

When should I use *zu Haus* and when *nach Haus*? For instance:

> *Ich fahrt nach/zu Haus.*
>
> *Ich gehe nach/zu Haus.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Correct is:

```
Ich fahre nach Hause.
Ich gehe nach Hause.
```

*Ich fahre/gehe nach Haus* (without *e*) is more colloquial.

If you on the way to your home, you use `nach`.
If you are already at home, you use 'zu Hause`or`zuhause`.

```
Ich bin zuhause.  (I am at home)
Ich komme zuhause an (I arrive at home)
Ich esse zuhause (I eat in)
```

Comment: *Morgen werde ich zu Hause sein.*

Comment: Ich bin in Berlin zu Hause. Eben kam ich nach Hause. Bald bin ich zu Hause.

Comment: thanks for explaining. just one question. so can we say-
Ich gehe nach Zuhause. thanks K

Comment: "nach Haus (without e) is more colloquial". I disagree, at least in my experience (Northern Germany) people would always say *nach Hause*. *nach Haus* sounds Southern to me.

Comment: It's either "nach Hause" or "zu Hause"/"zuhause". You cannot use both "nach" and "zu" at the same time. (Just as in English, you don't say "I go to at home" either). You *can* treat "Zuhause" as a noun, but then you **have** to specify whose home it is and you have to use "zu" instead of "nach", e.g. "Ich gehe zu meinem Zuhause" (although this might sound a bit weird/convoluted).

Answer (score 24):

This is simple :)

nach Hause - **Where are you going to?** Home. Direction no matter how you get there.

zu Hause - **Where are you?** (At)Home. Current location. Also for to stay

von Zuhause - **Where are you coming from?** (From) home. "Origin"

This rule applys to any action. What matters is the question word.

> From where are you calling? Von Zuhause.

Comment: "Current" trifft es nicht. Wo warst Du zu Hause? Wo wirst Du zu Hause sein? Die See ist sein Zuhause. Origin?

Comment: How did it happen?  If Zuhause means at home,you said then with 'von Zuhause' from at home :/

Comment: Does this only apply to the noun Haus? For instance, I read the following in a text: "Ich werde zum Supermarkt gehen.
Ich gehe zum Supermarkt.
Ich bin zum Supermarkt gegangen."

Answer (score 7):

I have just made an explanation video about this topic: ["zu Hause" or "nach Hause" explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpRH2QOgoug)

Excerpt:

**Being in a location:**

```
Ich bin zu Hause.
I   am  at home.
```

**Moving to a location:**

```
Ich gehe nach Hause.
I   go   home.
```

It is quite confusing if you only recall "zu" as "to" in German (which would be the direct translation), since "zu Hause" would translate to "to home" which is incorrect in this case. Better remember "zu Hause" as one term, this makes it easier: `zu Hause = at home`

Other example sentences:

```
She will send the package home.
Sie wird das Paket nach Hause senden.

At home, it is beautiful.
Zu Hause ist es schön.
```